# Python dataframe - data values from 3 columns to be mapped under other 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Python experts, I need some help understanding how I can re-shape or pivot columns of my pandas dataframe. Following is what I want to do, I have a situation where I have 6 columns First_name1, middle_name1, last_name1, first_name2, middle_name2 and last_name2. I want to bring the values of the last 3 columns under the 1st 3 columns, like some sort of pivoting but not exactly.

```
First Name 1    Middle Name 1   Last Name 1 First Name 2    Middle Name 2   Last Name 2
    ABC      DAF                 XYZ          LOU           NaN      XYZ
```

I am unable to understand how to do it. I only need 1st 3 columns existing after this operation. 
Any help would be certainly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) for `MultiIndex` and then reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit(n=1, expand=True)
print (df)
  First Name Middle Name Last Name First Name Middle Name Last Name
           1           1         1          2           2         2
0        ABC         DAF       XYZ        LOU         NaN       XYZ

df = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  First Name Last Name Middle Name
0        ABC       XYZ         DAF
1        LOU       XYZ         NaN
```

Another solution with undocumented function  `lreshape`:

```
d = {'First Name':df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('First Name')],
     'Middle Name':df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Middle Name')],
     'Last Name':df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Last Name')]}

df = pd.lreshape(df, d, dropna=False)
print (df)
  Middle Name First Name Last Name
0         DAF        ABC       XYZ
1         NaN        LOU       XYZ
```

Comment: Why did you remove lreshape?

Comment: In past I have very fire discussion about it, so always add it as alternative now

Comment: Yeah I have seen them :)

Comment: What if there are other more columns after these 6? I get a value error saying that "total size of new array must be unchanged". How do I get around that?

Comment: I think it should working nice. What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: The thing is that these columns have an address1 and address2 columns which have to be just copied for both the fname1 and fname2.

Comment: My solution need colname + space + number. So I ask for real columns names, because it seems there is some difference. So what is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dataframe construtor and values reshape i.e

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,3),columns=['First Name','Middle Name','Last Name'])
```

```
 First Name Middle Name Last Name
0        ABC         DAF       XYZ
1        LOU         NaN       XYZ
```

Sample run on  multiple row data i.e

```
   First Name 1 Middle Name 1 Last Name 1 First Name 2  Middle Name 2 Last Name 2
0        ABC         DAF       XYZ        LOU          NaN       XYZ
0        ABC         DAF       XYZ        LOU          NaN       XYZ
```

Output :

```
 First Name Middle Name Last Name
0        ABC         DAF       XYZ
1        LOU         NaN       XYZ
2        ABC         DAF       XYZ
3        LOU         NaN       XYZ
```

Comment: I will recommend careful  use `lreshape`, if you want some function see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typically [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html) question , one line code as below :

```
pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ["FirstName", "MiddleName","LastName"], i="index", j="year").reset_index(drop=True)
Out[506]: 
  FirstName MiddleName LastName
0       ABC        DAF      XYZ
1       ABC        DAF      XYZ
2       LOU        NaN      XYZ
3       LOU        NaN      XYZ
```

Comment: why index and year ?

Comment: @Bharathshetty df.reset_index() , keep unique key which is 'index', year you can name what ever you want , I usually drop it after convert